# Visual Studio 2010 aspx editor adds markup

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Has anyone experienced VS 2010 adding unnecessary markup?

It's not auto-completing unclosed tags or anthing like that. Some reformatting and injection of seemingly random elements (`<h3></h3>`) for instance, seems to be happening.

Comment: Are you going often in Design mode and drag and dropping controls from the ToolBox?

Comment: I've seen VS do lots of quirky things, but I've never seen it add random HTML by itself...  When you notice this, what are you doing?  Are you work in Source or Design view ?

Comment: @Zack - Source view, then hitting Save. It's not happening to me, another team member, so thats about as much as I know

Comment: I'd check to see if they have any Add-ins, maybe they have something doing a clean-up/reformat on save.